# swiperefreshlayout in bottomsheet not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recyclerview in a bottomsheet, and that works fine. When I introduce a swiperefreshlayout around the recycler view, it doesn't allow me to scroll up, it only collapses the bottomsheet. I would like it scroll the recycler view, reach the top and then trigger a refresh. If I need to, I'm okay with getting rid of the drag to collapse behavior on the bottomsheet.

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" >

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:visibleGone="@{ model.locPerms }"
            app:onRefreshListener="@{ () -> model.refreshPois() }"
            app:refreshing="@{ model.refreshing }">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_pois"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                tools:listitem="@layout/poi_item"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you dont need behavior like that hide it when you scroll up, you can add `app:behavior_hideable="false"` to your ConstraintLayout. in other case you must catch onSlide down and make some actions there.

Comment: Not sure if is a good idea to have a SwipeRefreshLayout inside a bottom sheet, but if you really want to try maybe you should try wrapping the ***SwipeRefreshLayout*** inside a ***NestedScrollView***.

Comment: I am also facing this problem, Any one handled it ??

Answer (score 7):

Try disable nested scrolling on the recylerView

```
list_poits.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```